# PHP fatal error depending on... browser type?

Tags: php, browser, runtime-error, server-side, php-include

The situation described below caused a fatal error in PHP in about 50% of the *browsers* whereas in other browsers the code ran normally. No browser or any client info sniffing was used. As far as I know this should not be possible (PHP running differently depending on client browser). The issue has been resolved but I still want to understand exactly how this could happen.

So index.php includes 2 files:

```
include('a.php');
include('b.php');
```

a.php:

```
the_function();
```

b.php:

```
function the_function(){
  //code
}
```

The fatal error in 50% of the browsers was that the_function was not defined in a.php, so a.php was executed immediately upon include. Whereas in other browsers it seemed to first include all php files and only then start executing.

If I remember correctly they were Mac Safari, Mac Chrome, and IE but I don't even know whether this behavior is shared among the same browsers on different machines.

the issue of course was resolved by switching the order of includes. But I still want to understand why this happened.

Comment: Because you try to access an function which are not avaliabe.

Comment: I understand that Andreas, please read my entire question. I want to know how it can be that this gives a fatal error in some browsers and in some browsers not

Comment: Were these tests run on the same server or different servers

Comment: Same single server. The behavior as I described occurred while visited from several clients visiting the site from different IPs. If you are interested to try but cannot reproduce, I can rebuild the situation on the server where it happened

Comment: That might be interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure but as far as i know this behaviour can happen when the PHP code is cached in APC or another bytecode cache. For this reason sometimes the code is already cached and the function is available at beginning.

In PHP you can define the function later than calling it and it works, if you are in the same file.
Example: https://3v4l.org/m951d

So, it not depends on the browsers, it depends on the current cache status for the php script.